# Unable to access docker.sock after system restart if jenkins is running in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, containers

```
 ERROR: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping : dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I tried changing everything from giving sudo privileges to docker.sock
and changing sock permission to 666.
I know its a security issue. but the permission changes get overridden on each system restart.

I wanna either persist the permission.
or fix the sock.connectivity issue between jenkins container and system host.

I tried doing everything which stack overflow had to offer but i am not able to persist either the permission of sock to 666
or get the issue fixed first hand without modifying the permissions to 666.

Comment: When you launch Jenkins, can you put it in the group that owns the Docker socket?  When you say "it's a security issue", any local process can very easily use the Docker socket to compromise the entire machine; `chmod 0666 /var/run/docker.sock` is very close to a "never ever do this" workaround to me.

Comment: Well that jenkins is not allowing. I have tried that already.

Answer (score 0):

I myself did a fix running the permissions with each restart was daunting, so i updated my crontab to fix the permissions.

But you guys will be surprised, that also didn't work out.
Because the docker.daemon always starts up late than your machine and it out of security implications again restricts the permissions.
After lots of head banging it got fixed.

```
    Until I did this thing.
    
    I told my script to run once the docker daemon is already up and running.
    So that the permissions are never overridden by docker daemon.
    
    1.I created a small script under /usr/local/bin/dockersock-permissions.sh
    setting up permissions.
    2.Then I created permission.service under /etc/systemd/system/dockersock-permissions.service
    3.sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dockersock-permissions.sh
    4.sudo systemctl enable dockersock-permissions.service
    5.sudo systemctl start dockersock-permissions.service

and voila I never looked back again to that nasty error of the jenkins container not able to connect to docker.sock on host.




root@hanisntsolo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/home/hanisntsolo# cat /etc/systemd/system/dockersock-permissions.service
[Unit]
Description=Set Docker Socket Permissions
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dockersock-permissions.sh

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
root@hanisntsolo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/home/hanisntsolo# cat /usr/local/bin/dockersock-permissions.sh
#!/bin/bash
chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock

Lastly you can check if everything went fine with below :: 
root@hanisntsolo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M:/home/hanisntsolo# systemctl status dockersock-permissions.service
○ dockersock-permissions.service - Set Docker Socket Permissions
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dockersock-permissions.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2024-01-30 21:29:43 IST; 1h 13min ago
    Process: 12435 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dockersock-permissions.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 12438 ExecStart=/bin/chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 12438 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 9ms

Jan 30 21:29:42 hanisntsolo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M systemd[1]: Starting Set Docker Socket Permissions...
Jan 30 21:29:43 hanisntsolo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M systemd[1]: dockersock-permissions.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jan 30 21:29:43 hanisntsolo-To-be-filled-by-O-E-M systemd[1]: Finished Set Docker Socket Permissions.
```